# Android Edittext keyboard issue?

Tags: android, keyboard

In one of the Application Am using Edittext for edit the data, some times Working fine and some times some Error is come(See Error log Below)

```
 07-11 17:27:40.003: E/SpannableStringBuilder(18003): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 07-11 17:27:40.003: E/SpannableStringBuilder(18003): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
 07-11 17:27:40.023: D/AndroidRuntime(18003): Shutting down VM
 07-11 17:27:40.023: W/dalvikvm(18003): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41838300)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41f6f0b0 is not valid; is your activity running?
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:585)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:988)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:845)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:809)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.updatePosition(Editor.java:2147)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.widget.Editor$PinnedPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:2104)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:2349)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.widget.Editor.showSuggestions(Editor.java:1647)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.widget.Editor$1.run(Editor.java:1546)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 07-11 17:27:40.023: E/AndroidRuntime(18003):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the Xml file am useing

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_popup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
```

Main activity class is this

```
  Another seperateclass = new Another(Mainactivity.this)
  button.setOnClickListener(seperateclass );
```

And Here is my class Function

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mainactivity);
            final View deleteDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.custom_popup, null);
            final AlertDialog deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainactivity).create();
            deleteDialog.setView(deleteDialogView);
            final EditText input =(EditText)deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.editText_popup);

            input.setText(addr3_title);
            input.setSelection(input.getText().length());

  }
```

`Note1:` That edit text display in popup dialog.

Comment: can you pleas post your activity code ?

Comment: @Haresh that is not a activity, just separate class.

Comment: What is mainactivity??

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA  mainactivity is separate, in main activity onCreate() method just passing mainactivity context to that class class.

Comment: And this code is also in mainactivity class?

Comment: no this code is seperate class not in mainactivity see am adding mainactivity class.

Answer (score -1):

From the other issue: [Error : BinderProxy@45d459c0 is not valid; is your activity running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811993/error-binderproxy45d459c0-is-not-valid-is-your-activity-running)
Probable your activity is finishing while your dialog is still alive. Try doing like DiscDev said on his answer to be sure that the activity is alive when your dialog is visible.

```
if(!((Activity) context).isFinishing())
{
    //show dialog
}
```

Comment: take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662239/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-unable-to-add-window-on-buider-s . Might help you =)