# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@292fbfb is not valid

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Android Studio 3.4

```
public class SubscribesFragment extends SubscribesBaseFragment {

 @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            mActivity = (Activity) context;
        }
}
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(ExistSubscribeWidget.ACTION_REFUSE_PAPER_INVOICE)) {
                String providerGUID = intent.getStringExtra(ProviderWidget.EXTRA_PROVIDER_TAG);
                String notificationSubscribeOwnerKey = intent.getStringExtra(ExistSubscribeWidget.NOTIFICATION_SUBSCRIBE_OWNERkEY);
                showConfirmDialogRefusePaperInvoice(context, providerGUID, notificationSubscribeOwnerKey);
            }
        }
    };

    private void showConfirmDialogRefusePaperInvoice(Context context, final String providerGUID, final String notificationSubscribeOwnerKey) {
        final Activity actitivity = mActivity;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(actitivity);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.refuse_paper_dialog_title);
        View customView = AndroidUtil.getLinearLayout(actitivity, R.layout.refuse_paper_dialog);
        builder.setView(customView);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              //some code
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.show(); // crash here
    }

}
```

but app crash :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.myproject.app, PID: 6376
 android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@292fbfb is not valid; is your activity running?
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
    at com.myproject.app.fragment.SubscribesFragment.showConfirmDialogRefusePaperInvoice(SubscribesFragment.java:108)
    at com.myproject.app.fragment.SubscribesFragment.access$000(SubscribesFragment.java:38)
    at com.myproject.app.fragment.SubscribesFragment$1.onReceive(SubscribesFragment.java:60)
    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:313)
    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:121)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: close your dialog before destroy your fragment

Comment: @RajasekaranM   
    public void onStop() {
        if (dialog != null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }  - not help. Same error

Comment: you are displayed dialog inside broadcast receiver. which purpose you are used?

Comment: can you comment dialog call in broadcast receiver and try?

Comment: @RajasekaranM I need to show dialog when received broadcast action "ACTION_REFUSE_PAPER_INVOICE"

Comment: may be it's trigger after your activity destroyed. confirm you activity is not destroyed before show dialog

Comment: @RajasekaranM this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/14488827/6813231

Answer (score 1):

You are using brodcast recover context to show dialog. Use activity context for that.